# Upload image from android phone to the Asp.net server

Tags: android, asp.net, image-uploading, procedural-programming

I searched many links but not able to find the solutions. As i dont have much idea about coding Asp.net  . Can any one help me about the procedure with example to upload a image from the imageview to the Asp.net server.

thanks in advance

Comment: you can use this [link](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/) for reference, And I think it doesn't mater whether its php server, Asp.net server or java server. Thnx.

Comment: Refer this tutorial: [ANDROID – Upload an image to a server](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the same way as in JME.[check this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME). Uploading images is done through HTTP post and 
multipart/form-data content type which is accepted by all server side languages, so it should work in ASP.NET in the same was as it works in PHP.

Comment: Can i have a simple and procedural coding which illustrate about the code